# Eliminate 0's in MMULT

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY))))))`

The formula produces an array, in which blank cells are interpreted as 0. How do I get rid of all 0 in the produced range? I've tried to FILTER() it with

`=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(MMULT(N('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY))))),'E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY<>0))`

but that produces `FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern

```
=IF(formula=0,,formula)
```

In your case the final formula is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
MMULT(N('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY)))))=0,,
MMULT(N('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E0:Sample'!$D$2:$AY)))))
))
```